# Password change in Application1 doesn't apply to Application2

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio

I have installed a *WebApplication1* in **Machine1** and *WebApplication2* in **Machine2**.

In both applications I have a Menu for changing my password. Both applications access the same `oracle` db/table.

The problem is if I change my *password* in WebApplication1, I can use the new *password* **only** in WebApplication1. In WebApplication2 I am able to login only with the old password, although in the Database I see the new password. If I start the Projects in debug mode I don't have this problem.

Why am I facing this problem?

**EDIT** After I restarted the Application Pools everything works OK.

Comment: what have you tried?? Please show some code so people can answer your question

Comment: "In both applications I have a Menu for changing my password" .. which password? The application password, or the schema password? If the former, where is the password stored? If the latter, are both applications logging into the database with the same schema?